# What does od mean in mean in pseudo-code?

Tags: pseudocode

My lecturer has presented me with the following pseudo-code:

```
at each timer interrupt
do

• perform analog-to-digital
conversion to get y;

• compute control output u;

• output u and do digital-to-analog conversion;

od
```

I am wondering what `od` could mean in this context?

Maybe it is part of the programming language I am not aware of?

Comment: Pseudo-code literally has no set format, it's just a rough layout of the algorithm that you intend to write and its format will vary from person to person. That said, `od` seems as if it is the end of the loop.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. You should just ask your lecturer.

Comment: I think @AStopher pretty much answered my question. The lecturer uses this format frequently.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

'do' and 'od' is a "mirror" text block instruction that start with "do" and read software lines and end instruction with "od", because symbols "{" , "}" not is allowed,not exist, or means other type of instruction. some pseudo-code type with a limited set of instructions like architecture 'RIS' has compilators that read it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the end of the `do` block. At first I thought it was a loop but it may just be a block that executes once.